# Contrast error in lm function, even after removing values without variation

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am new to r so please forgive me if this is very simple to fix. But the title says i am trying to run a multiple regression with price as my dependent variable, and the rest of my variables except city as the predictors.
It keeps giving me the below error even after i removed "city" as a variable in the regression (it only has the same value repeating)
All the other variables have unique values so im not sure what im doing wrong to keep getting this error?
Any help is much appreciated! I tried to attach pictures of my error but stack isnt letting me attach images..the error im getting is :

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

First time getting the error i had city included as a predictor, but then i checked my variables and saw city is the only one without unique values, so i removed it from the lm function with -city

Comment: The error suggests one of your variables has no variance.

Comment: Actually the error says there is a variable with only one level among the cases that survived the removal of any case with an NA. If we are to offer further advice it should be after you show us the output of `summary( na.omit( dfrm) )` where `dfrm` is the name of the data object being given to `lm`. At the moment it's simply a "not reproducible" sort of question. Voting to close.